# one of WFE cannot be browsed

Tags: error, load-balancing

In our SP2010 farm there are 2 WFE (WEB01 and WEB02) and 2APP servers. Between users and 2 WFEs there is a network load balancer.

Last week, by unknown reason, users are not able to browse Sharepoint pages thru one of WFE server (WEB01):

1. Some users browse thru network load balance address he has half chance get "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" error.
2. If browse thru `http://web01` user will 100% get "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" error.
3. Browse thru `http://web02` is alright.
4. Browse thru `http://web01:1234` or `http://web02:1234` (the Central Admin page) is alright
5. Browse thru `http://web01:9999` or `http://web02:9999` (another web application) is alright.

UPDATE: after further investigate, I think Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event may not be the direct cause.
Although user cannot browse `http://web01`, he can direclty type in `http://web01/Pages/Welcome.aspx` and browse the page. Hence, I think all the sites under `http://web01` web application have problem to redirect users to the default HOME page. How can I fix it?

On Web01 server event log I found error:

> SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event:
>   EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 5911 AppDomain Name:
>   /LM/W3SVC/123456789/ROOT-1-1234567879878978 AppDomain ID: 2 Service
>   Application Uri:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:267adbb783e241d9a55a9916933680b1#authority=urn:uuid:5578be51c5254ac09f5cde1d0fd12f3f&authority=`https://APP01:32844`/Topology/topology.svc
>   Active Endpoints: 1 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint:
>   `http://APP02:32843`/394adbb783e241d9a88a7716733680b1/ProfileService.svc

How should I troubleshoot it?

Comment: looks like one WFE bad for http://web01, Did you try to reset the App Pool on the server or IIS reset on the web01 server?

Comment: I have tried reboot all 4 servers at the same time and situation no update.

Comment: can you browse the site on the server(web01), what about other web apps are you able to browse them on that server? check the IIS settings on the web01 for the web apps, if using SSL make sure SSL certs properly bind with server and also if you have any antivirus on the server, try to disable that and check if it is working

Comment: Waqas, I found it is the HOME page have problem. Please see the update.

Comment: check this one http://prequest01.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/unable-to-open-sharepoint-sites-without-defaultaspx/

Comment: Waqas, actually you gave me the answer in earlier reply! It end up Web01's SSL have problem. When I check the IIS entry the SSL cert is not selected. I imported the SSL again and bind the IIS entry fix it!

Comment: Maybe you want to reply this thread and let me mark as answer?

Comment: good to know, i added it as answer, Please mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can browse other web applications on the server except the `http://web01` then looks like something wrong with the IIS Bindings.
Please make sure

- IIS Bindings for the web app in place
- If using the SSL, make sure SSL bindings & Certs attach to the web app.
- another possibility is AV causing the issue, try to disable it.